# Kilogram is SI unit but not gram at the same time meter is SI unit and not kilometer. What decides whether a unit should be considered as SI or not?

Tags: conventions, si-units, metrology

centi, milli,kilo,micro etc all are prefixes used in SI system of measurement.  So in centimeter both the prefix-centi and meter belong to SI system but centimeter is not SI unit. If it is not SI unit then should we call it non-SI unit.

OR
Should we say both meter and centimeter are SI units but meter is the coherent SI unit?

Answer (score 3):

The SI is defined in the BIPM’s “The International System of Units” brochure, currently in its 9th edition.

https://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure

> centimeter is not SI unit

This is not correct. Section 2.3.4 says that “The complete set of SI units includes both the coherent set and the multiples and sub-multiples formed by using the SI prefixes.”

> Should we say both meter and centimeter are SI units but meter is the coherent SI unit?

That is correct and is described also in section 2.3.4. The meter is a coherent SI unit. The meter is also a base unit. Although the distinction is less important now than it was in previous editions.

> What decides whether a unit should be considered as SI or not

The BIPM (Bureau of Weights and Measures) decides. It has a very lengthy process for deciding. Once it has decided the definition is published in their brochure, referenced above.